# How to write an automated Build script to checkout the code from subversion and perform the build

Tags: msbuild

I have to write a build script to checkout the code from subversion repository and perform the build. 
I am literally a starter to scripting.
Please let me know some sample scripts that could help me, we use .net and i want to write the script in MSBuild.
What if I have to checkout the code from repository to a remote server or perform a build on the build server.

Thank You,
Rocky

Answer (score 4):

You can use custom tasks and targets from http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/
It has some stuff to work with VCS

Or you can do it manually with command line svn.exe tool something like this

```
<Exec Command="svn.exe" CommandArgs = " export $(SvnFullPath)/$(MSBuildProjectFile) $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/$(MSBuildProjectFile) --force --non-interactive" ContinueOnError="True"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [CruiseControl.NET](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/)

Cruise control is a continuous integration server, it watches svn and does builds automatically whenever anything is checked in. It integrates with visual studio, so you don't' need to write the build scripts by hand.

When something breaks, it sends out an email.

You can also set it up to do do one off builds for releasing code. Take a look it is pretty nice.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that and i know hudson, but our lead wants script and not the continuous intigration. can any one help me with the scrips...

Comment: Take a look at this for writing build scripts in msbuild http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9883dzc.aspx

Comment: I agree with Bryon's answer that you want a build server.  Ask your lead the reason why he'd want a script vs a build server.  In my builds I use bat files to launch the build.  That way a developer can double click the bat file which runs the build and produces a buildLog.txt.